# Lost ability to authenticate software installation etc from GUI after deleting pi user. Can still install command line

Tags: raspbian-buster, gui, sudo

In the interest of increasing security of my pi I followed the [Secure Raspberry Pi Guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/security.md)

After doing so and deleting old pi user and rebooting I now cannot authenticate sudo from the GUI. For new software installation for example.

My new user does not appear in the drop down box: only root and pi.

I want to add my new user and delete pi from the GUI authetication boxes.

I can still mount LUKS drives etc from command line so all is working - but use of the GUI is sometimes easier.

Using Full Raspbian Pi Desktop from January 2020. So up to date.

It said some usability can be lost on deleting default pi - but the aim was to reduce this in later version of pi desktop.

Answer (score 2):

After several hours of posting my question here I searched on google and the very same problem with solution had been posted in 2016.

Here is the URL https://blog.gyt.is/2016/03/01/how-to-create-a-new-user-on-raspbian-powered-raspberry-pi/

The solution below is the applicable part to that webpage with just the solution, rather than the background:-

After digging into polkit little bit more I discovered it offers a variety of privilege options. One of them is administrative actions that those nice programs like gufw, gparted and others require. Go ahead and edit following file:

```
sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/60-desktop-policy.conf
```

Find part where it has:

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-user:pi;unix-user:0
```

And add your new user with unix-user:YOURUSER  (type all of this in and change YOURUSER for username that is missing of your list of users from the drop down menu. Don't forget it needs to be followed by a semi-colon ";" to separate it from the following user)

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-user:YOURUSER;unix-user:pi;unix-user:0
```